# Why jsoncpp append function will cause an assert error

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am a newer to Jsoncpp and I used it in my c++ projects。Sometimes I found a wired error like this:

```
Json::Value val;
val["1"] = 1;
val["2"] = 2;

Json::Value arr;
arr["name"] = "wjx";
arr["age"] = 23;
arr["id"] = 17777;

val.append(arr);
```

this will cause a error named Json::throwLogicError，But the similar code below run rightly

```
Json::Value val;
val["first"] = 1;
val["second"] = 2;

val["fourth"] = "wjx";

Json::Value root;
root.append(val);
```

I don't konw the reason,And I find no talk  on the Internet so I ask for help.Who can explain this sitution.

Answer (score 3):

`append` only makes sense for `arrayValue`, that is list-type JSON values.

When jsoncpp creates a value, by default, it starts as a `nullValue`. If you then perform array-style operations on it like `append`, it'll turn it into an `arrayValue` and carry on. This is what happens when you write

```
Json::Value root; // Root starts as a nullValue
root.append(val); // Root becomes an arrayValue
                  // and from now on array-type behaviors are okay
```

But that doesn't work in your first code snippet. Because similarly to `append` causing a conversion from `nullValue` to `arrayValue`, using `operator[]` with string keys to do assignment converts it into an `objectValue`, a collection of key-value pairs. (`operator[]` with integer keys would have turned it into an `arrayValue`, since in a JSON object keys must be strings.)

```
Json::Value val; // val starts as a nullValue
val["1"] = 1;    // val becomes an objectValue
                 // and from now on dict-style operations are okay
val["2"] = 2;

...

val.append(arr); // ERROR: val only accepts dict-style operations
```

To see why a dict-style `Value` can't accept `append`, ask yourself what key should be associated with the value you're `append`ing.

Comment: Thank you very much!And I try to add key like this:val["arr"].append(arr);It's right!